# Streaming data events aren't registered

Tags: node.js, supertest, superagent

I'm using `superagent` to receive a notifications stream from a server

```
require('superagent')
  .post('www.streaming.example.com')
  .type('application/json')
  .send({ foo: 'bar' })
  .on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log('chunk:' + chunk); // nothing shows up
  })
  .on('readable', function() {
    console.log('new data in!');   // nothing shows up
  })
  .pipe(process.stdout);           // data is on the screen
```

For some reason `data` and `readable` events aren't registered, hovewer I can pipe data to the sceeen. How can I process data on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source of [`pipe`](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/94afa3ae189267a8d352d72b20edb9900148959e/lib/node/index.js#L489) method, you can get access to the original `req` object and add listeners on it:

```
require('superagent')
  .post('www.streaming.example.com')
  .type('application/json')
  .send({ foo: 'bar' })
  .end().req.on('response',function(res){
      res.on('data',function(chunk){
          console.log(chunk)
      })
      res.pipe(process.stdout)
  })
```

But this won't handle the redirection if any.

Comment: Perfect. Works with `supertest` too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `superagent` doesn't return a real stream, but you can use something like [`through`](https://github.com/dominictarr/through) to process the data:

```
var through = require('through');

require('superagent')
  .post('www.streaming.example.com')
  .type('application/json')
  .send({ foo: 'bar' })
  .pipe(through(function onData(chunk) {
    console.log('chunk:' + chunk); 
  }, function onEnd() {
    console.log('response ended');
  }));
```

(although you have to check if `superagent` won't first download the entire response before it sends data through the pipe)